# type-hinting attributes of one class from attribute type of another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I have two related classes for pydentic models:

```py
class TargetBase(BaseModel):
    url: str = Field(
        default="google.com", 
        title="Target URL",
        )
    port: int = Field(
        default=443, 
        gt=0,
        title="Target URL port number",
        )
```

Both attributes are required.

Next model specifies a `PATCH`-structure which should accept request with any of attributes having null or `None` value like:

```py
class TargetPatch(BaseModel):
    url: str | None = "google.com"
    port: int | None = 443
```

I do not wish to redefine `Field()` values for all attributes in `TargetPatch`-class, as this may result in `Field()` specification diverting from each other on later modifications.

I tried something like:

```py
class TargetPatch(BaseModel):
    url: str | None = TargetBase.url
    port: int | None = TargetBase.port
```

But python tells me TargetBase has no `url` attribute.

and I had to settle with redefining the `Field()`-values for `TargetPatch` class-attributes:

```py
class TargetPatch(BaseModel):
    url: str | None = Field(        # None is the extra requirement in this class
        default=None, # "google.com",  [Edited]
        title="Target URL",
        )
    port: int | None = Field(       # None is the extra requirement in this class
        default=None, # 443,  [Edited]
        gt=0,
        title="Target URL port number",
        )
```

How can I *Sync* `Field()`-values for attributes of both classes and making `TargetPatch`-class attributes to accept `None` values?

I could figure out, this problem needs accessing default value of class-attribute from another class. Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't having default values in the PATCH request mean that they get the default value if left out of the `PATCH` request? So if you want to only update `port`, you suddenly get `google.com` as the default value for `url`? (Not sure if this is the actual behavior as that would depend on your view, but `None` would probably be better if given explicitly? (and then only fetch the defined fields when extracting them from the request). So - while not actually answering your question; default values for patch requests seems a bit unconventional?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, I have corrected my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Field()` seems to create `pydantic.fields.FieldInfo` objects. I think you can use `copy.deepcopy()` to create deep copies and update just the necessary attributes in the copies. If you want to access the `FieldInfo` of a field you can use `__fields__[<name>].field_info`.

Check the following example. I used python `3.9.7` (that is the one I had at hand and the reason I use `typing.Optional`) and pydantic `1.10.2`.

```python
import copy
from typing import Any, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.fields import FieldInfo


class TargetBase(BaseModel):
    url: str = Field(default="google.com", title="Target URL")
    port: int = Field(default=443, gt=0, title="Target URL port number")


def _copy_field_info(field_info: FieldInfo, **kwargs: Any) -> FieldInfo:
    print("FieldInfo to copy:", id(field_info), repr(field_info))
    field_info_copy = copy.deepcopy(field_info)
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        setattr(field_info_copy, name, value)
    field_info_copy._validate()  # Field() does this internally
    print("Copied FieldInfo:", id(field_info_copy), repr(field_info_copy))
    return field_info_copy


class TargetPatch(BaseModel):
    url: Optional[str] = _copy_field_info(
        TargetBase.__fields__["url"].field_info,
        default=None
    )
    port: Optional[int] = _copy_field_info(
        TargetBase.__fields__["port"].field_info,
        default=None
    )


print(repr(TargetBase()))
print(repr(TargetPatch()))
```

Output:

```
FieldInfo to copy: 2265963690048 FieldInfo(default='google.com', title='Target URL', extra={})
Copied FieldInfo: 2265968680000 FieldInfo(title='Target URL', extra={})
FieldInfo to copy: 2265963689792 FieldInfo(default=443, title='Target URL port number', gt=0, extra={})
Copied FieldInfo: 2265968680256 FieldInfo(title='Target URL port number', gt=0, extra={})
TargetBase(url='google.com', port=443)
TargetPatch(url=None, port=None)
```